# HttpClient post with no return data throws error

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I am making a post request from my angular application to a web api. The api will return either a 200 status or a 404 status. In either case, it doesn't return any data. E.g. some of the headers for the 200 response are `{ "content-length": "0", "content-type": null }`. My Typescript making the post to the api looks like:

```
return this.http.post(url, "", { params: params }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        throw "";
    });
```

The problem is, I get an error even for the 200 response: `Unexpected end of JSON input`.

How do I receive and check the response code so that I can ultimately return true for success or false for failure?

Comment: well just don't return your post result directly. If i remember `this.post` return an `HttpResult`. Once you have your result in a variable you can do any check you want

Comment: It's a known issue, that is being fixed: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18680

Comment: I used the suggested interceptor to workaround the issue

Comment: I just saw the interceptor that creates a new HttpResponse on a 200 error. Thanks! For some reason, the first time I looked I only saw the one that changes the responseType to text.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use syntax like this and pass the header parameters.

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this.http.post(this.url, {param:param}, options)
                   .map(this.data) //your data format
                   .catch(this.handleErrorObservable);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The map does not help me as an error is thrown before it is executed.

Answer (score 0):

I think your are missing on the subscribe method, you have not given space for the success callback. If you are using the HttpClient use Subscribe and no need for the map but if you have the setup for Http use map.

I suggest you use HttpClient which is new from angular 4.3.X and have some awesome methods to do a various different tasks.

```
this.http.post(url, "", { params: params }).subscribe(msg=>{this.postResult = msg; console.log(msg);}, err=>{ console.log(err); throw "";});
```

Comment: The subscribe is in the calling function (not shown.) The execution however does not get that far as an error is thrown first. Yes, I am using HttpClient.

Comment: have you tried creating the HttpErrorResponse object instead and throw that?

Comment: Thanks, that does seem like a possible workaround.

Comment: I think you would have to do somethign like this,

return Observable.throw(new HttpErrorResponse({status:401, statusText:"Ohh this looks like fail"}));

Comment: What I did was convert the error into a non-error: `.catch((err: HttpErrorResponse) => { if (err.status == 200) return ""; else throw err; }`

Comment: Why dont you write the .catch method also at the calling function? this might help you. You can also setup Interceptor in your angular 4 application to take care of this error, let me know if you want to setup Interceptor.

Comment: Using a catch on the calling function would unnecessarily be allowing the "error" to propagate. It's better to deal with the error as early as possible. Thanks, @JBNizet has given a link to an interceptor in his comment above.

Comment: Ohh then using the interceptor would solve your problem, you will be able to take care of the error much before it lands on your UI.